# How to get data from form input

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im new to mobile development, especially using Ionic. Please help me out

I have this code for my route

```
.state('auth', {
url: '/auth',
templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
controller: 'AuthCtrl'
```

I have this code for my login.html

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
<ion-content class="padding">
    <div class="list list-inset">
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" ng-model="mobile_number">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password">
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
</ion-content>
```

and for my AuthCtrl

```
.controller('AuthCtrl', function($scope,$auth,$state) {

$scope.login = function() {
    var credentials = {
        mobile_number : $scope.mobile_number,
        password : $scope.password,
    }
    console.log(credentials);
    $auth.login(credentials).then(function(data) {
        // If login is successful, redirect to the users state
        $state.go('tab.dash', {});
    });
}
```

})

I always get this **Object {mobile_number: undefined, password: undefined}** when calling *console.log(credentials)*
I always put values in my forms, but its always undefined. Why?

Comment: post your module and route config

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First initialize your scope credentials model:

```
$scope.credentials = {
   'mobile_number' : ''
   'password' : '',
 }
```

Then bind your inputs to the scope properties:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number" ng-model="credentials.mobile_number">


<input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="credentials.password">
```

And make use of `$scope.credentials` that now has your form data:

```
$auth.login($scope.credentials).then(function(data) {
    // If login is successful, redirect to the users state
    $state.go('tab.dash', {});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your credentials object is not bound to scope. It looks like You need to declare $scope.credentials outside of login. Also on the input, ngModel should bind to credentials.password and credentials.mobile_number.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it works good for me, I did a little [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/58jKXlJfSoGAhvDuAtsh) to test it. I was facing similar problem cause I added ng-pattern and ng-minLength directive in the input. In this case you will get undefined unless the input value is valid pattern and length. To fix it I added property to your input element

```
<input type="tel" ng-model="credentials.mobile_number" 
  ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}"/>
```

I hope that helps , good luck